# How to create an object from yaml file declared as interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I have an enum similar to this

```
enum class API : APIInteface {
    API_A{
        override processApi(toProcess: Any){
            return "A"
        }
    },
    API_B{
        override processApi(toProcess: Any){
            return "B"
        }
    };
    override abstract processApi(toProcess: Any)
}
```

And `APIInteface` with  only one method `processApi(toProcess: Any)`

In my service I want to declare a field like this:

```
@Value("\${api}")
private lateinit var apiDeclaration: APIInteface
```

And in my config.yml I have `api: API_A`

I know if apiDecaration's type is `API` it works ok, but I need to declare it as APIInteface. Obviusly it did not work because `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type`.
And here is my question, How can I tell object's type it must create in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best option but it works.

I have create a new service

```
@Service
class APIFactory {
    @Value("\${geo.api}") 
    private lateinit var apiDeclaration: API

    fun getApi(){
        return apiDeclaration
    }
}
```

and in my previous service I declare it as I want

```
private lateinit var apiDeclaration: APIInteface
```

and call ApiFactory::getApi method to poblate it